# php - extracting numbers from a string containing a pattern

Tags: php

I have a string like this

```
4-1,4-1,,,1-1,,5-4,2-1,
```

and I need to extract the first number in each pair. For example, (**4** -1, **4** -1,,, **1** - 1,, **5** - 4, **2** -1 ,)

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '4-1,4-1,,,1-1,,5-4,2-1,';

preg_match_all('/(\d+)-/', $string, $matches);
// search for 1 or more digits that are followed by a hyphen, and return all matches

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 2
)
```

Comment: Think I'll accept this answer as it's less code. Thank you both

Answer (score 1):

```
$couples = explode(",", $data);
$values = Array();

foreach ($couples as $couple)
{
    if ($couple != "")
    {
        $split = explode("-", $couple);
        $values[] = $split[0];
    }
}
```